# BASH - file selection by multiple patterns in zenity

Tags: bash, design-patterns, filenames, zenity

Im pretty new to zenity and bash. Im trying to make file selection window that will display only the ones with .ogg, .aac and .wav extension. I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
option=`zenity --file-selection --file-filter=*.ogg | *.aac`
```

For one extension it's working as intented:

```
option=`zenity --file-selection --file-filter=*.ogg`
```

Zenity man provides information:

```
--file-filter=NAME | PATTERN1 PATTERN2
Sets a filename filter
```

I dont really understand how am I supposed to use it. Can someone show me some examples?

Comment: I haven't zenity, so only guessing. So, try this: `--file-filter="*.ogg|*.aac"`

Comment: Yeah, thansk for the effort :) This one gives only the ones that ends on .aac.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I found the solution, maybe someone will use it in the future:

```
zenity --file-selection --file-filter=""*.ogg" "*.wav" "*.aac""
```

Comment: And indeed it is helpful in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer, I don't think I would have figured that out on my own.  But now that you pointed me in the right direction, I found how to do descriptions and multiple dropdown options too - hope you don't mind the edit :)

Comment: Those quotes are mostly unnecessary.  Just use `"*.ogg *.wav *.aac"`.

Comment: It seems as if the quotes are interpreted by Bash and not zenity - this means that it works for you by luck because the files in the current directory are used as a filter.

Answer (score 8):

Special bash symbols | and * needs escaping (backslash) or quoting (single or double), and you have succeeded with that. With single quotes the argument is passed literally to zenity.

Repeat the --file-filter option if you want more filter choices
For example, you may want two filters "All files" and "Music files" in the file selection window:

```
zenity --file-selection --file-filter='Music files (ogg,wav,aac) | *.ogg *.wav *.aac' --file-filter='All files | *'
```

Comment: Until I saw this post, I had not tried multiple, separate `--file-filter="Filetype | *.foo"` flags. It hadn't even occurred to me! They should update their documentation.

Comment: The updated documentation can be found in https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lunar/en/man1/zenity.1.html