# Zenity: File selection dialog - case insensitive filetype filtering?

Tags: linux, shell, zenity

I was hoping some kind person who is more intelligent than me could help.

I am writing a small script to call various programs in the background and do various things so a list of PDF files that the user selects, using Zenity as a GUI of sorts.

Everything is working so far, but I have hit a roadblock:

The PDF files that the user selects might have different cases in their file extensions, e.g. `.pdf` of `.PDF` or even `.Pdf`

I would like the user to be able to select the PDF files they need, and only show PDF files, but since the sources of these files are unknown, it is possible that their extensions are in who-knows-what case, upper, lower mixed, who knows...

Is there a way to call a Zenity file selection dialog and filter all PDF files, regardless of the case (upper/lower) of their extension?

I have the following code so far:

`zenity --file-selection --multiple --file-filter='*.pdf | *.Pdf |*.PDF'`

BUT this is NOT a good solution as the person will have to select each option separately. I would like them ALL to be shown, no matter the case of the letters in the extension.

Thanks again for any kind help.,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BASH - file selection by multiple patterns in zenity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267042/bash-file-selection-by-multiple-patterns-in-zenity)

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and tinkered this solution which works for me.
Maybe you have some use for it as well:

```
zenity --file-selection --file-filter=*[PpDdFf]
```

have fun!